# "GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false" error

Tags: java, glassfish, illegalstateexception, illegalargumentexception, glassfish-4

I'm having problems with Glassfish 4.0 + Netbeans 7.4...
whenever i try to run my project i get this erros:

```
ant -f D:\\Projetos\\NetBeans\\Sullimar -Dbrowser.context=D:\\Projetos\\NetBeans\\Sullimar\\web\\index.html -DforceRedeploy=false -Dclient.urlPart=/index.html -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dnb.internal.action.name=run.single run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
In-place deployment at D:\Projetos\NetBeans\Sullimar\build\web
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
D:\Projetos\NetBeans\Sullimar\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

and my glassfish server output:

```
Informations:   visiting unvisited references
Informations:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:2869
Informations:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Informatios:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
Grave:   Cannot start container web, exception: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: virtual server server has an invalid docroot C:\Users\Thaís\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\domain1/docroot
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer

Grave:   Aborting, Failed to start container com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer
Grave:   Exception while deploying the app [Sullimar]
Grave:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: Aborting, Failed to start container com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:736)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:374)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Grave:   Exception while deploying the app [Sullimar] : Aborting, Failed to start container com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer
```

What do I do to fix these errors? In my Services tab I can access my databases, and my dabatase connection to my Sullimar database works fine (I can view the data...) so I can't underastand the problem.
Thanks a million!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with Netbeans 8 on Windows 8.1.  Tried switching to JDK 7 from JDK 8 but it did not help.  The server is running JDK 7 which did actually work with Netbeans 8 in Windows 7 on another machine.  I can connect to the server from Netbeans in the services tree but deploy just does not work with the same error `"GF4, deploy, null, false"
D:\src\java\netbeans\nbproject\build-impl.xml:336: 
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.`
The server log is completely blank, which is odd - I'm running debug mode.

Comment: did you fix your issue

Answer (score 3):

the error is easy, you need delete  in WEB-INF/web.xml

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your server.log file.
It's located under /$YouGlassfishRoot/glassfish/domains/$Domain/logs/server.log
The problem is probably your server's jdk version.

Answer (score 0):

Got the S.O.B to work. Turns out Windows firewall was blocking Netbeans (as it should), which for whatever reason requires incoming connections for deployment.

Try create a rule allowing inbound TCP for `C:\program files\netbeans 8.0\bin\netbeans64.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem on Windows 7, for you it's to late, but it could help somebody else. First there was no server.log file in GLASSFISH_INSTALATION_DIRECTORY\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs and the reason was that my user didn't have rights to write anywhere in GLASSFISH_INSTALATION_DIRECTORY (glassfish was installed with netbeans )

after fixing that I found "...Invalid resource : jdbc/..." exception and fix for that can be found at this webpage https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html under Troubleshooting paragraph